# Many-2-Many ERC721 Pattern?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I'm looking to build a smart contract with a function which is able to generate a unique and limited amount of ERC721 tokens based on an input string. I also want to be able to look up all the tokens based on the input string.

How should I go about approaching this complying with best practices?

**Example:**

I input the string "Cow", to a function in the smart contract.
Next, I should be able to create a parent token which represent the string, and each child token should have a numerical ID within the range 1-50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I input the string "Cow", to a function in the smart contract.
>   Next, I should be able to create a parent token which represents the string, and each child token should have a numerical ID within the range 1-50.

A contract factory could serve as both an ERC721 deployer and a registry (inventory) of the deployed tokens. ERC721, itself takes care of instances of COW.

A shortcoming of this approach is the cost of deploying each token contract. ERC1155 (multitoken) is a way of doing this in a single contract. In essence, the familiar functions with the addition of a token argument and another dimension in the storage layout.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for ERC1155, it perfectly fits the use case - https://blog.enjincoin.io/erc-1155-the-crypto-item-standard-ac9cf1c5a226

Comment: Thanks, I didn't give that standard a second thought, I for sure will now. Thank you fellas!